# Getting file access reports for file shares

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server with several file shares. Manager wants to have some kind of report with a daily total number of file reads for each user, like

```
      08/04/17
Jonh  4326
Mary  235
Bob   3865
```

So I have enabled event logging, and all the needed events could be observed with Event Viewer. What is the best option to query that log and generate user-friendly reports for the files that actually was accessed (i.e. copied from the server)?

Also it would be great to have a list of files accessed by users at a given date like

```
08/04/17 - Jobn
H:\Public\ImportantFolder\WorkingFile.xls
H:\Public\ImportantFolder\WorkingFile2.doc
... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get useful reporting based on the events you are now seeing, you will need to either write some sort of script which will parse the event log (Powershell, Python, Perl, ... come to mind), find a script that somebody else has already created, or install a third-party software product. The last option should be the easiest, but obviously has a cost associated with it.

I have had good experience with [EventSentry](https://www.eventsentry.com), which will automatically parse file access tracking events and provide reporting through a web interface (Compliance-File Access). This [link gives you an example](http://demo.eventsentry.com/fileaccess?search.type=summary&search.refresh=&search.group=user&search.agg=&search.union=&report=&pageDefault=&search.query=&search.dateRange=Last%203%20days&search.fromDate=&hour=&minute=&meridian=&search.fromTime=&search.toDate=&hour=&minute=&meridian=&search.toTime=&refresh=) of what a report could look like, reports can be automatically emailed as well.

If you search Google you will find a lot more products which provide this, including open source and other commercial offerings.